# Why does SymPy yield a "worse" solution than WolframAlpha?

Tags: python, sympy, solver

I needed to solve $sin(x)+a*sin(3x)=0$ symbolically for $x$.

```
import sympy as sp  
a,x = sp.symbols('a,x')
roots = sp.solve([sp.sin(x)+a*sp.sin(3*x)],[x])
print(roots)
```

produced

```
(I*(-log((-a - sqrt(-3*a**2 + 2*a + 1) - 1)/a) + log(2))/2,),  
(I*(-log(-sqrt((-a + sqrt(-3*a**2 + 2*a + 1) - 1)/a)) + log(2)/2),),  
(I*(-log((-a + sqrt(-3*a**2 + 2*a + 1) - 1)/a) + log(2))/2,)]
```

whereas WolframAlpha produced a much "better" solution:

```
solve sin(x) + a sin(3 x) = 0
```

yields

```
x = π n and n element Z  
x = 2 π n and a = -1/3 and n element Z  
x = 2 π n - 2 tan^(-1)(sqrt((5 a - 4 sqrt((a - 1) a) - 1)/(3 a + 1))) and 3 a + 1!=0 and sqrt((a - 1) a)!=2 a and n element Z  
x = 2 (tan^(-1)(sqrt((5 a - 4 sqrt((a - 1) a) - 1)/(3 a + 1))) + π n) and 3 a + 1!=0 and sqrt((a - 1) a)!=2 a and n element Z  
x = 2 π n - 2 tan^(-1)(sqrt((5 a + 4 sqrt((a - 1) a) - 1)/(3 a + 1))) and 3 a + 1!=0 and 2 a + sqrt((a - 1) a)!=0 and n element Z
```

**Question:**
can the SymPy solver be configured to produce solutions in the way WolframAlpha does?
Is anything known why SymPy expresses the solutions via (complex) logarithms instead of arc tangents?